# How to deploy an API Gateway custom authorizer without identity sources using serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, lambda-authorizer

I'm trying to create a custom lambda authorizer in API Gateway using the serverless framework.

The clients of my service may send either 'Authorization' or 'X-Custom' header (but not both). So what I need is a custom authorizer without an identity source.

The serverless YAML sniped is as follows:

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          authorizer:
            arn: xxx:xxx:Lambda-Name
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            type: request
          integration: lambda
          cors: true
          request:
            template:
              application/json: '{"method": "$context.httpMethod","body" : $input.json("$"),"headers": {#foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end},"queryParams": {#foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end},"pathParameters": {#foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end}}'
```

I'm using the following request template so that my lambda gets the headers and can perform the validation:

```
{"method": "$context.httpMethod","body" : $input.json("$"),"headers": {#foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end},"queryParams": {#foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end},"pathParameters": {#foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())"$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end#end}}
```

The problem is that when I run the serverless deploy command the authorizer is created with an 'Authorization' identity resource.

I based my code in the following resources:

- [Serverless endpoints with custom authorizers](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers).
- [Cloudformation AWS API Gateway Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html#cfn-apigateway-authorizer-authorizerresultttlinseconds).
- [Cloudformation AWS API Gateway Authorizer V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-authorizer.html).

This lead me to two questions:

1. what is the conformation version that the serverless framework is
   using to deploy my authorizer?
2. How do I specify a custom authorizer
   without resources?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
  identitySource: '',
  resultTtlInSeconds: 0 // You have to set this to 0.
```

Hope this saves people the pain I have just been through! :P

Comment: I would give you 3 upvotes if I only could! ;) Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me with empty string but did not need to use the resultTtlInSeconds: 0.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the serverless framework is conforming to the first version,
since it complained when i tried to set the value to an empty list.
Using and empty string solved it for me.

```
identitySource: ''
```